# Добавление элементов в список. System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Tags: c#, ооп, классы, list

Всем привет, совсем недавно начал программировать. У меня есть список Signals, в котором хранятся signal, внутри каждого signal должен быть список параметров и у каждого параметра должны быть значения, значения желательно тоже в списке.

На данном этапе я пытаюсь добавить параметры в существующий signal, но при попытке добавления вызывается ошибка:

System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Как её можно исправить, не совсем понятно

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Список с Сигналами
        List<Signal> Signals = new List<Signal>();

        //Добавляем новый сигнал
        Signals.Add(new Signal()  {VarName = "signal1"});

        //Просматриваем все сигналы в Signals
        foreach (var signal in Signals)
        {
            //Добавляем в сигнал параметр Time и значение
            signal.parameters.Add(new Parameters() { paramName = "Time", value = 1});
            foreach (var parameter in signal.parameters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(parameter.paramName, ":", parameter.value);
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class  Parameters
{
    public string paramName { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class Signal
{
    public string VarName { get; set; }
    public List<Parameters> parameters;

}
```

Ошибка в этой строке:

```
signal.parameters.Add(new Parameters() { paramName = "Time", value = 1});
```

Comment: `parameters` не инициализирован, т.е. в нем хранится `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поправьте так:

```
    //Добавляем новый сигнал
    Signals = new List<Signal> 
    {
       new Signal 
       { 
          VarName = "signal1",
          parameters = new List<Parameters>()
       }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Signal
{
    public string VarName { get; set; }
    public List<Parameters> parameters = new List<Parameters>();
}
```

Comment: зачем этот костыль? зачем создавать то, что никогда не будет использоваться(возможно)

Comment: @pashagoroshko у вас своеобразное определение костыля. Если поле не используется, то его нет смысла создавать, это да. В смысла всё поле нет смысла определять, если оно не используется

Comment: @pashagoroshko, а как обычно это реализуется?

Comment: @ЧирковИлья поля обычно инициализируются либо на месте, как показал я выше, либо в конструкторе, либо указываются при создании экземпляра

Comment: @ЧирковИлья ответил

Comment: @tym32167 а если у меня там null, то при маппинге будет что происходить? а ну да, вначале создадим пустую коллекцию, а потом присвоим null :) гениально

Comment: @tym32167 либо через конструктор в моделях, или правильнее делать на уровне логике все манипуляции с моделями

Comment: @pashagoroshko вы сами придумываете кейсы, которых нет в вопросе? В вашем воображаемом коде ваш вариант конечно лучше :)